# How to format selecting data using SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite, format

Currently doing some selecting exercises using SQLite 3 on Python 3. This all works fine, however I want to format the output onto the shell. At the moment, when I run this program:

```
def select_all_products2(tech):
    with sqlite3.connect('movie.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select * from User where userOccupation=?",(tech,))
        products2 = cursor.fetchall()
        return products2

products2 = select_all_products2("technician")
print(products2)
```

It just prints all the matching fields out in a long, ugly list. Is there a way I can format the output onto the shell, say, with a \n after each field so it's much more easier to read?

Comment: check https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Comment: This is not specific to SQLite results. You have a list of rows, each row a tuple. Any question about how to format lists and tuples trivially applies.

Comment: you can also use [pandas read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, an SQL result set is an iterable so you can start with

```
for product in select_all_products2("technician"):
    print (product)
```

Then you realize that a row is also an iterable which makes it quite possible to format the output into nice looking columns.